# How to push to an array values from inside an arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, arrow-functions

I'm trying to push to an array even numbers inside an arrow function but I don't how to push it in to that array.

My code:

```js
var arrayEvenNumbers = [];
var evenNumbers = (arrayEvenNumbers) => {
  for (i = 2; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      arrayEvenNumbers.push(i);
    }
  }
}
console.log(evenNumbers(arrayEvenNumbers));
```

Really I'm a beginner and I've learned a bit, but I'm trying my best

Hope someone could help me to improve

Also I don't know if I'm sending the arguments properly
And I'm not native english speaker so excuse if I can't express correctly :)

Comment: You're not returning anything. In `EvenNumbers` `return arrayEvenNumbers;` after your loop.

Comment: Thanks man, after return works fine

Answer (score 2):

this way

```js
var arrayEvenNumbers = [];

const evenNumbers = arr =>
  {
  for (let i = 2; i <= 20; i++)  
    if (i % 2 == 0)  arr.push(i);
 
  return arr
  }

console.log( evenNumbers(arrayEvenNumbers) )

console.log( arrayEvenNumbers )
```

Comment: Thanks man, it{s so helpful

Answer (score 1):

`evenNumbers` pushes it correctly, but returns undefined. You're probably looking to do:

```
evenNumbers(arrayEvenNumbers);
console.log(arrayEvenNumbers);
```

Comment: Ye, that's what I forgot, thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is the code you've forgotten the **return** statement:

```js
var freeArr = [];
var evenNumbers = (arr)=>{
    for(i = 2; i <= 20; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            arr.push(i);
        };
    };
    return(arr);
};
console.log(evenNumbers(freeArr));
```